# ignoring a group with the D3 nest function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some data where, in a given column of a csv, there are six possible values:
1,2,3,4,5,NaN.

I am currently trying to group the data using the d3.nest and rollup functions. My goal is to group the data but exclude "NaN" values in the final output.

This is my current code:

```
            var nested = d3.nest()
                           .key(function(d){return d[question];
                           })
                           .rollup(function(leaves){
                                var total = data.length
                                var responses = leaves.length;

                                return {
                                    'responses' : responses,
                                    'percent' : responses/total
                                };
                            })
                           .entries(data)
```

As you can see, I would like to return both a count of each of the categories as well as the percentage of the total that they represent. After removing NaN, I would also like the removal of NaN represented in percentage values of all of the other categories so that they sum to 100%.

Comment: I would remove the rows with `NaN` before passing the data to `d3.nest()`.

Comment: That makes a ridiculous amount of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to remove the rows the contain `NaN` before passing the data to `d3.nest()`:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(d) { return d.question !== 'NaN'; });
```